# Include Box2D libraries to a cocos2d project (iOS)

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-iphone, ios, cocos2d

I have a problem including box2D to my cocos2d project. I've tried different ways to do it with no success. This is what I've done:

- I downloaded Box2D (Box2D_v2.2.1) to my project directory.
- Dragged the Box2D directory (which includes -> /Box2D.h, /Collision, /Common, /Dynamics, /Rope) to my Xcode project (from Finder to Xcode)
- Then I added #include "Box2D.h" to my .h file and got many errors... Here is where I started my research :P
- I went to Project Settings and edited the attribute **Header Search Paths** (contained in the **Search Paths** section) specifying the path of Box2D. At this point, I builded the project and I got *less errors*.
- After that, I renamed my **.m file** to **.mm** (I think this is because Box2D is written in C++ and with this, the compiler can treat it as it is). Still got errors.
- Then I tried changing the attribute **Always Search User Paths**
  (contained in Project Settings -> Search Paths) from **YES** to
  **NO**. Still got errors.
- As my last option I tried changing the attribute **Compile Sources
  As** (contained in Project Settings -> LLVM GCC 4.2 - Language) from
  **According to File Type** to **Objective-C++**.

By now I'm frustrated xD. I have 203 errors and most of them are in the .h files contained in the Box2d engine.

**b2Timer.h** - Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'b2Timer'

**b2Distance.h** - Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'b2DistanceProxy'

**b2Math.h** - Cfloat: No such file or directory

And so on...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Cocos2D binding provided, never the Box2DLibrary as-is. If you have already starter your project without it the best thing I can recommend is either start a new template with Box2D included this time and import all the code (less painful than expected) or hardlinking "box2d.h" already included in the cocos2d folder "cocos2d-iphone\external\Box2d"

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. That's what I did :P I thought it would be painful but it wasn't (Y).

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the procexdure in here:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_1._install_test

and installed the cocos2d, it would have added cocos2d-box2d and cocos2d-chipmunk templates that comes in new project window of xcode.

By creating projects this way, all the libraries are integrated and setup by default.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering... Well, I have those templates but I didn't create my project that way. I created a project with the first template that appears (cocos2d only). Now I want to incorporate Box2D to my project...

Answer (score 0):

If all its wrong, you may create a new project directly from box2D, and migrate everything. It's the last thing I can think of. You have made everything already so this is a last resort. It might work.

Comment: I'll try that as my last resort. That should work.

Comment: Any issue, ask :)

Answer (score -2):

You need brew to install cmack, then use it to install Box2D.

Comment: What's "cmack"? This is quite vague. Why do you think this would solve the problem?